# How to abort all workflows in Informatica

Tags: informatica, abort, informatica-powercenter

I did not know where else to post this as there are Informatica questions on this site. But at present, in order to `abort` workflows in Informatica, I must right click each workflow and manually select abort:

[image]

Given I have several hundred workflows active at any one time, to then `abort` them all manually takes a very long time.

Is there a programmatic or pre-defied GUI to allow for aborting all workflows at once?

Comment: You could write a script that loops through the list of all workflows and executes the `pmcmd abortworkflow` command for each one.

Comment: @Samik where is the script window? Can you provide a sample script?

Comment: I was talking about external Shell scripts on the Informatica server, it is not inside the PowerCenter application. You can start or stop workflow using the command `pmcmd` in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You could dump the Integration Service. That would abort all workflows.

Otherwise you'd need to create a script to abort the workflows with pmcmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all workflow names in a file (or get the workflow list from repository using repository query) and pass each workflow to the below pmcmd command which will automatically abort it using shell script.

pmcmd abortworkflow -service informatica-integration-Service -d domain-name -u user-name -p password -f folder-name -w workflow-name

pmcmd aborttask -service informatica-integration-Service -d domain-name -u user-name -p password -f folder-name -w workflow-name task-name

Let me know if you need any additional help.